# using useRef for a textbox to handle outside click not working - React functional component

Tags: reactjs

am just giving a minimal code to tell about my issue am facing now

I have a textbox

which is being given as

```
<input type="text" ref={inputRef}/>
```

and

```
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("click", handleClickOutside, false);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", handleClickOutside, false);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleClickOutside = event => {
    if (inputRef.current && !inputRef.current.contains(event.target)) {

    }
  };
```

But here am getting an error like
**TypeError: inputRef.current.contains is not a function**

Not sure how to check the same for input text box

Here what am trying to achieve is need to get control if user click outside the input text box
Note: i had done the same for div and component , but for text box , not sure

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: This code works, can you reproduce the problem in a sandbox as expected? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-template-forked-njj1z?file=/index.js

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code snippet of a function to handle the outside click.

```
const useOutsideClick = (ref, callback) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
      if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
        callback();
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, [ref, callback]);
};
```

Usage inside a component:

```
...
const inputRef = useRef(null);
useOutsideClick(inputRef, callbackToHandleOutsideClick);

return <input type="text" ref={inputRef}/>;
...
```

You have to use similar kind of code to make it work.